# UIView. How do I place a subview behind it's parent superview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm doing a bit of UIView wrangling and am stuck. It is straightforward changing the "z" order of sibling subviews. [mySuperview sendSubviewToBack:mySubview] places mySubview behind all it's siblings.

But how do I place a subview behind it's parent?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: This cannot be done as it goes against the fundamental relationship between view and superview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to put both into a container view, so that you can properly place one behind the other without affecting a superview not really meant to hold arbitrary views (although that will probably work just fine).

Comment: Thanks Kendall. Yes, that looks like my only option. It's too bad altering the 'z' relationship between parent and child is not available. Probably has something to do with the iPhone compositing engine. Cheers.

Comment: One other thing I ran across, you could try altering the "anchorPointZ" property of the view.layer... I'm not sure which way you would set it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't as far as I know. You'll have to remove it from the parent then add it to the parent's parent's subviews.

```
UIView *parent = view.superview;
[view removeFromSuperview];

/* Adjust frame to realign under parent view */

[parent.superview addSubview:view];
```