# Drawing a view in back of a view (added as a subview)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview

Inside my view I have added couple of subviews. Now in this view hierarchy I want to move the frame of one subview a little up keeping the subview on top of it remaining unaffected. Its more like moving the view to back and keep playing with the positions. Is it possible with UIView to tell it always remain in back when drawn as a subview inside a view.

Answer (score 4):

Yup. Use a master UIView and add all your subviews to that. Once you tell one to stay back, it stays back. You can then just play with the frame. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507174/uiview-how-do-i-place-a-subview-behind-its-parent-superview). **Edit:** The question of the post has the answer, i.e. `[myUIView sendSubviewToBack:subView]`

Adding multiple UIViews to another UIView is like adding objects to a stack. The most recent addition is on top.

Comment: How will I tell one subview to stay back? Please share sample code for this.

Comment: UIView sendSubviewToBack. Check UIView class reference for additional details.

Comment: @TheBlack: Can you post ur reply as a answer of this question so that I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Access the array of subviews on a view by doing:

```
[view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2];
```

Thanks to [TheBlack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107311/theblack) for correcting my previous answer...

Comment: dharth Iyer exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex: of UIView is correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For the view which you want to bring in front, you can add it to self as :

```
[self addSubView:xyz z:1];
```

And for the view which you want to display in back, you can try :

```
[self addSubView:abc z:0];
```